# How to correctly type Svelte events with no detail: null, undefined or void?

Tags: typescript, types, dom-events, svelte, svelte-component

I'd like to know which would be the correct way to type an event that receives no parameters, something like:

```
import { createEventDispatcher } from 'svelte';

const dispatch = createEventDispatcher<{
 discard: undefined; // or should it be null, void?
}>();
```

And then later I would just dispatch it like this, with no detail at all:

```
<button on:click={() => dispatch('discard')}>Cancel</Button>
```

From what I could test, in this short example when dealing with this event event.detail would be `null`, and [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent/CustomEvent#parameters) states the same, but I would still like to know if it should be typed as `discard: null;`, `discard: void` or any other way.

Comment: Does createEventDispatcher<{discard:{}}>() work (I haven't tried it)? I would instinctively use an empty object {} to signify there are no parameters on the event as it follows the convention set by events with parameters.

Comment: Sorry, didn't edit in time. Looking back at my own notes discard:void is what I wrote down. I'm not sure where I found that but it appears to be in some documentation or examples. I'm not sure which one is best. However, null or {} are the most logical since they are both of type object. undefined is its own custom type and void is basically undefined.